Boton html 5 para agregar (abrir) contactos en smartphone
Para preguntar si hay alguna forma en html 5 / javascript de abrir la app de contactos en los smartphone
se que con esto podemos acceder a la aplicación de "llamadas"
<a href="tel:7777252019">Llámanos</a>

existirá alguna forma de abrir la aplicación de "contactos" para agregar uno nuevo ??

No, y es por seguridad, imagínate que cualquier web pueda abrir tus contactos??  Lo que se hace es abrir la App de llamadas y ahí, con ese numero puedes guardarlo, pero ya es algo propio de la App de llamadas

Como indican en los comentarios, permitir que una página web añada a los contactos directamente sería un problema de seguridad y no se puede hacer (al menos, no de momento*), pero podrías intentar un enfoque indirecto.
La idea sería crear un vCard o Fichero de Contacto Virtual (VCF por su nombre en inglés: Virtual Contact File) y enlazarlo en tu página web. Si usas el atributo download podrías darle un nombre representativo a la descarga. Cuando el usuario pulse en el contacto, se le preguntará si quiere añadirlo a los contactos.
Puedes hacerlo con un fichero .vcf o usando una URI de datos. Por ejemplo, imagina que tienes la siguiente vCard:
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Falsete;Falso;;;
FN:Falso Falsete
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123-456-7890
EMAIL:falso@falsete.com
END:VCARD

En tu página podrías tener un enlace como éste:
<a href="falso-falsete.vcf" download="falso.vcf">
  Añade a Falso Falsete a tus contactos
</a>

Si lo haces usando una URI de datos, la vCard debe estar codificada como URL, y lo podrías tener todo en el HTML, sin necesidad de un fichero externo. Si el vCard no es amplio, esta podría ser una opción viable también:
<a href="data:text/vcard;urlencoded,BEGIN%3AVCARD%0AVERSION%3A3.0%0AN%3AFalsete%3BFalso%3B%3B%3B%0AFN%3AFalso%20Falsete%0ATEL%3BTYPE%3DCELL%3A123-456-7890%0AEMAIL%3Afalso%40falsete.com%0AEND%3AVCARD" 
   download="falsete.vcf">
  Añade a Falso Falsete a tus contactos
</a>


En ambos casos el fichero se descargará en el teléfono y el usuario podrá añadir el contacto. Como ves es un proceso que requiere 2-3 pasos en vez de uno solo. Pero podría funcionar.

*Pongo "no de momento" porque JavaScript cambia rápidamente y cosas que antes se consideraban imposibles por motivos de seguridad (p.e. leer del portapapeles, usar la cámara o leer de la lista de contactos de un teléfono), ahora son posibles y existen APIs para esas acciones. Nunca se sabe.
